# Spring Integration DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm trying to test some stuff with spring-integration using the DSL. The flow is as follows:

1. create some messages
2. process them (insertUpdateMergeAdapter, deleteAdapter)
3. aggregate them
4. perform some operation once messages are processed (cleanupAdapter)

The flow looks something like this
Setup adapter (Polled) -> messageHandlerChain (inbound adapter -> Outbound adapter(insert/delete) -> cleanup adapter)

```
return flowDef
            .channel(receiveChannel)
            .handle(inboundAdapter)
            .split(insertDeleteSplitter)
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("ALC_operation", "payload[0].get(\"operation\")"))
            .routeToRecipients(r -> r
                    
                    .recipientFlow("'I' == headers.ALC_operation or 'U' == headers.ALC_operation",
                    f -> f
                            .split(insertSplitter)
                            .channel(insertUpdateChannel)
                            .wireTap(sf -> sf.handle(insertUpdateMergeAdapter))
                            )
                    .recipientFlow("'D' == headers.ALC_operation", f -> f
                            .split(deleteSplitter)
                            .channel(deleteChannel)
                            .wireTap(sf -> sf.handle(deleteAdapter))
                            )

                    .defaultOutputToParentFlow()
                    )
            .aggregate()
            .channel(cleanupChannel)
            .wireTap(sf -> sf.handle(cleanupAdapter));
```

the cleanup Adapter fails to do any operation.

I get the following exception:
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available

Following is the expected spring integration flow I am trying to achieve

[Expected spring integration flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJdnf.jpg)

EDIT:

```
return flowDef
        .channel(receiveChannel)
        .handle(inboundAdapter)
        .split(insertDeleteSplitter)
        .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("ALC_operation", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_operation\")")
                .headerExpression("ALC_startTime", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_startTime\")")
                .headerExpression("ALC_endTime", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_endTime\")")
                .headerExpression("ALC_object", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_object\")")
                .headerExpression("ALC_schema", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_schema\")"))
        .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
                .applySequence(true)
                //no need to return to the main flow after this operation
                .subscribe(f -> f
                        .filter("'I' == headers.ALC_operation or 'U' == headers.ALC_operation")
                        //Message has one to n rows
                        .split(insertSplitter)
                        //Messages now split into one message per row
                        .handle(insertUpdateMergeAdapter)
                        //All rows have been inserted or updated
                        .enrichHeaders(
                                h -> h.headerExpression("ALC_operation", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_operation\")")
                                        .headerExpression("ALC_object", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_object\")")
                                        .headerExpression("ALC_schema", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_schema\")")
                                        .headerExpression("ALC_startTime", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_startTime\")")
                                        .headerExpression("ALC_endTime", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_endTime\")"))
                        .channel(insertUpdateChannel)
                        .aggregate()
                        //Aggregate processed messages so we have one operation per table to cleanup
                        .enrichHeaders(
                                h -> h.headerExpression("ALC_operation", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_operation\")")
                                        .headerExpression("ALC_object", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_object\")")
                                        .headerExpression("ALC_schema", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_schema\")")
                                        .headerExpression("ALC_startTime", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_startTime\")")
                                        .headerExpression("ALC_endTime", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_endTime\")"))
                        .handle(cleanupAdapter)
                        //This is the end of the flow
                        )
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you show more around that stack trace, but anyway I don't think that flow must be so complicated according to you diagram. How about the way like this?

After `split()` you use a `PublishSubscribeChannel` to send the same message to the "CRUD" sub-flow and forget. In this flow you could do that `enrichHeaders()` and standard `route()` (not `routeToRecipients()`) and have this flow stopped after an appropriate branch to be executed.

The second subscriber would be your aggregator. This way you send the same message to the router flow for your DB operations, wait in the main flow until it finishes and send exactly that message to the aggregator.

What you have currently with the `routeToRecipients()` and those `wireTap()` doesn't look good and feels like an abusing of those operators when our flow might be much simpler and smoother.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the input, I looked into the business logic and changed above code. I think it still needs improvement. Can you please review it once and let me know what is missing

Comment: According to the current config, it doesn't look like you need that `publishSubscribeChannel()`. It does have only one subscriber so far I see. So, probably just move all the sub-flow into a main flow and see how it works for you.

Comment: There will be additional subscribers with similar flows - up to 30 parallel flows that are all very similar but not consolidatable into a single flow. Once the first subscribed flow is working, the others will be built up one at a time.

Comment: OK. Then better to make them as a saparate `IntegrationFlow` beans and use their references in this main flow for this `publishSubscribeChannel()` declaration. This way your main flow won't look so complicated and hard to read.

Comment: :D  Clean coding practice - yes, externalizing the construction of the inner flow will make it much easier to follow.

Comment: Hi thanks for the input, I tried testing above flow but I get the following error :-      
No poller has been defined for endpoint '2dd85c34-e67b-46b2-9487-2e2440e837e5.subFlow#0.subFlow#0.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#5', and no default poller is available within the context. Can you please let me know what is missing, it is going wrong around aggregate function

Comment: See docs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#endpoint-pollingconsumer and follow those links about the `Poller` and `Channel Adapter`. As long as you start using a `QueueChannel`, you need a poller to be configured: or explicit on the consuming endpoint or a default one.

Comment: Hi Artem, It looks to me like we are following a completely wrong path here.  The splitter/aggregator that is being such a problem was put in place as a temporary workaround until we could figure out how to use the jdbc batch API's through spring integration. I I see you resolved that issue a couple of years back (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/2534). If you can confirm that this is the case, then we can close this question.

Comment: Yes, the `JdbcMessageHandler` supports now a `batchUpdate()` API from the `NamedParameterJdbcOperations`. If you need that in your logic, feel free to try. Not sure what is your question then, since the business logic is on your side and I'm fully off what is your final goal.

Comment: We're re-factoring and simplifying the flow enormously, and will submit a new question if we have any further issues.  Thank you for your generous assistance.